# randomizing a list in python manually

Tags: python, list, random

Here's some code for shuffling a deck of cards manually.  I understand it up to the point where `cards[pos], cards[randpos] = cards[randpos], cards[pos]`.  What is happening here?  What is the point of assigning cards[pos] to cards[randpos]?

self.cards is a list of playing cards in standard order.

```
  def shuffle(self):
        n = len(self.cards)
        cards = self.cards
        for pos in range(n):
            randpos = randrange(pos,n)
            cards[pos], cards[randpos] = cards[randpos], cards[pos]
```

Comment: You do know about `random.shuffle()`, right?

Comment: yeah, but I just wanted to see how this worked

Comment: But you really should avoid [this algorithm](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html) and just use `random.shuffle`.

Comment: This looks like a KFY shuffle to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically randomly swapping cards. It's taking `cards[pos]` out of the deck, placing `cards[randpos]` at its location, and placing `cards[pos]` back at where `cards[randpos]` was.

Also note, that Python provides [`random.shuffle`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle) so that you don't have to do this manually.

Answer (score 3):

The values of `cards[pos]` and `cards[randpos]` are being switched. This is a common Python idiom: you can switch two or more variables' values by saying `a, b = b, a`.

Note that [the standard library implementation of shuffling (`random.shuffle()`) is quite similar](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/random.py?view=markup#l276).

Comment: “quite similar” but [very different](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html) in “randomness”. The Python library function results in better “randomness”.

Comment: @ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ Correct. It was my way of saying "use the standard library, they already do it for you". Btw, your name is quite difficult to type...

Answer (score 1):

It's swapping the positions of the cards in `pos` and `randpos`.

So, for example, if your list were `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` and pos were `0`, first it would pick an index that comes after the `1` in the list. Then it would swap the `1` and the number at that index. So if `randpos` is 3 on the first iteration, we end up with `[4,2,3,1,5,6,7]` after one time through the loop.

As a side note, it is much more efficient (and reliable) to use [random.shuffle()](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle).

Answer (score 1):

In python

```
a, b = b, a
```

is how you swap two variables. In your code what are swapped are the contents of the list at position `pos` and `randpos`.

Answer (score 1):

```
cards[pos], cards[randpos] = cards[randpos], cards[pos]
```

This is simply swapping `cards[pos]` and `cards[randpos]`

Here's an entire Web page on the technique:  http://blog.mithis.net/archives/ideas/64-python-swap-var

Answer (score 1):

`cards[pos], cards[randpos] = cards[randpos], cards[pos]`

Is swapping the card at index pos with the card at index randpos

It's basically assigning card[randpos] to card[pos] and card[pos] to card[randpos].  Another way to do it would be

```
t = card[pos]
card[pos] = card[randpos]
card[randpos] = t
```

The former is just shorter and more pythonic.